# Can I force an enemy to reveal themself?

Tags: guild-wars-2

According to the wiki:

> [**Stealth**](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Stealth) (http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Stealth)
>
> Hitting a foe with an attack breaks stealth; if the attack missed, was blocked, or was evaded, they will not break stealth. Abilities that do not deal direct damage (like Caltrops, or the Traps which do not deal direct damage) will not break stealth, even though they apply damaging conditions. When a character breaks stealth, they gain the Revealed effect which prevents the user from re-entering stealth for several seconds, regardless of the skill used. The Revealed effect is not applied if the stealth ends normally.

Based on this, it sounds as though a player can only be taken out of stealth if they themselves deal damage, meaning that leaving stealth is always a deliberate action. It also sounds like conditions do not count (eg. a thief applies multiple stacks of bleed to me and goes into stealth while they are ticking) as "hitting a foe with an attack."

Is there any way to force a stealthed player out of stealth?

Comment: Fears and knockbacks will force a player out of stealth.

Comment: @Gwen I don't think it forces them out of stealth (not sure), but it does keep them off your back

Comment: I think knockbacks and fears work for [Shadow Refuge](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Shadow_Refuge), but that's it and only if the player is forced out of the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't force a player out of stealth in regular pvp (other than having them attack you).
It should be possible in WvWvW however:

- In wvw you can use Toxic Unveiling Volley with arrow carts (requires arrow cart mastery lvl 5)
- You can also use Stealth disruptor traps that reveal your opponent.

In regular PvP or in PvE, you can prevent stealth by applying revealed to your opponent:

- "Sic'em" (Ranger skill) can prevent an opponent from going into
  stealth by applying revealed to them
- Engineers can use Analyse (utility goggles toolbelt skill) to apply
  revealed

These skills are targetted however, and can't be applied to a target already in stealth

There are a few other ways to deal with stealth:

1. Damaging conditions betray their location (damage indicator).
2. AoE damage can help you force them out of a certain area (unless they are prepared to take the damage, but in that case you also see their location from the damage indicator).
3. Moving around semi-randomly makes it harder for others to backstab you
4. Using Fear, AoE knockdown and AoE knockback, as @Gwen pointed out - I don't think it breaks their stealth (not sure, should test), but it does keep them off your back for a few seconds and stealth tends to have a short duration.

See http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Revealed

Comment: Is "Sic 'em" the only way to prevent stealth?

Comment: @Koviko Updated my answer